# split values of a column and store only numeric values in a different column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in long table format like this one below:

```rb
mydf <- data.frame(id = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123),
                    name =c("test_2001", "test_2002", "test_2003", "test_2004", "test_2005"),
                    value = c(15, 20, 25, 30, 35))
mydf
#>    id      name value
#> 1 123 test_2001    15
#> 2 123 test_2002    20
#> 3 123 test_2003    25
#> 4 123 test_2004    30
#> 5 123 test_2005    35
```

Now, I want to split attributes from column `name` in such a way that I could remove those numeric values and store them in another column named `year`, output like this:

```rb
desired <- data.frame(id = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123),
                      name =c("test", "test", "test", "test", "test"),
                      year =c(2001:2005),
                      value = c(15, 20, 25, 30, 35))
desired
#>    id name year value
#> 1 123 test 2001    15
#> 2 123 test 2002    20
#> 3 123 test 2003    25
#> 4 123 test 2004    30
#> 5 123 test 2005    35
```

How can I automate this step considering I have to apply this change to a lot of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
cbind(mydf, strcapture("(.*)_(.*)", mydf$name, list(name="", year=1L)))
#    id      name value name year
# 1 123 test_2001    15 test 2001
# 2 123 test_2002    20 test 2002
# 3 123 test_2003    25 test 2003
# 4 123 test_2004    30 test 2004
# 5 123 test_2005    35 test 2005
```

### dplyr/tidyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>%
  separate(name, into = c("name", "year"), sep = "_")
#    id name year value
# 1 123 test 2001    15
# 2 123 test 2002    20
# 3 123 test 2003    25
# 4 123 test 2004    30
# 5 123 test 2005    35
```

(Note that with this, `year` is a string, can be converted to ints with `as.integer`.)

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, c("name", "year") := tstrsplit(name, "_")][]
#       id   name value   year
#    <num> <char> <num> <char>
# 1:   123   test    15   2001
# 2:   123   test    20   2002
# 3:   123   test    25   2003
# 4:   123   test    30   2004
# 5:   123   test    35   2005
```

(Again, `year` here is still a string.)

Comment: Thank you @r2evans

Comment: For this specific case, the default `sep` will do the trick, so `separate(name, into = c("name", "year"))` is enough

Comment: It works great for cases like this `test_2001` but I just find out that if the name is something like this `test_area_sqkm_2001`, then it doesn't work. Any idea how to solve this case?

Comment: There are at least a few ways that that string could be interpreted, you need to better define what you expect.